# How to import keycloak module using standalone components and without NgModule (v17)

Tags: angular, keycloak

I've just created a new angular application (v17). AppComponent is a standalone component and `main.ts` looks like

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

When the app boots I want (if not done yet) keycloak to kick to authenticate and redirect to the keycloak login page.

So I modified `appConfig`:

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService],
    }
  ]
};
```

The problem here is that `KeycloakService` is never provided. If you google you see examples which use `NgModule` in which `KeycloakAngularModule` is added to the `imports` array, which I don't have (everything is standalone components.

So my question is, should I create an `app.module.ts` file an do

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ KeycloakAngularModule, ...],
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

or is there an other way to do this with angular 17?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the `KeycloakService` as provider.

```js
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService]
    },
    KeycloakService // <-- add your missing provider here
  ]
};
```

**UPDATE**
This answer specifically fixes the following error:

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for _KeycloakService!
```

Here is a more complete version of the `app.config.ts` file with a factory function from [Keycloak Angular#Setup](https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular?tab=readme-ov-file#setup):

```js
import { APP_INITIALIZER, ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

import { routes } from './app.routes';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService]
    },
    KeycloakService
  ]
};

function initKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () => keycloak.init({
    config: {
      url: 'http://localhost:8080',
      realm: 'your-realm',
      clientId: 'your-client-id'
    },
    initOptions: {
      onLoad: 'check-sso',
      silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin
        + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html'
    },
  });
}
```

Your standalone components should also import `KeycloakAngularModule` if needed:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { KeycloakAngularModule } from 'keycloak-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    RouterOutlet,
    KeycloakAngularModule,
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'keycloak';
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why your configuration @John should work. I have the same setup as Jeanluca Scaljeri:

An angular 17 standalone application, I want to add IAM with keycloak, I use latest npm libs keycloak-angular and keycloak-js.

With this setup and your (@John) appConfig it does not work. 
Could you explain your solution?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Tell me if it is helpful.

Comment: I removed SSR configuration to get it work, without the import of KeycloakAngularModule in App Component. With the import of the Module, i get a keycloakService is null error. But either way, I still have the issue, that my Authorization header is not appended to my server requests.

Comment: I recommend that you create a new question because your issue looks different. You should also give the exact error logs.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Here 2 follow up in case of interesst: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77905410/configure-angular-17-standalone-to-work-with-keycloak