# Configure Angular 17 standalone to work with Keycloak

Tags: angular, authorization, keycloak, angular17, keycloak-angular

**Issue**

I'm working with an Angular v17 app configured in standalone mode, experiencing issues integrating with Keycloak libraries. Specifically, Keycloak isn't automatically appending the authorization header to backend requests. For security reasons, I prefer not to manually handle the Authorization Token.

- I installed Keycloak libs "npm install keycloak-angular"
- I added a provider for the Keycloak init
- I added some test code to signin and execute a request

All this code is working well with Angular non standalone (NgModule). But since I switched to standalone in angular 17, something is fishy.

To test my code, I have configured an Interceptor: authInterceptorProvider. That is adding the Token manually to each request. Works well. But I don't want to handle tokens by hand...

What might I be missing or configuring wrong?

**Code bits (image upload is not working at the moment)**

Here my simplyfied Application config

```
  export const initializeKeycloak = (keycloak: KeycloakService) => {
return () =>
  keycloak.init({
    config: {
      url: 'http://localhost:8180/',
      realm: 'balbliblub-realm',
      clientId: 'blabliblubi-public-client',
    },
    initOptions: {
      pkceMethod: 'S256',
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/dashboard',
    },
    loadUserProfileAtStartUp: false
  });}


export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
providers: [provideRouter(routes),
  provideHttpClient(
    withFetch(),
    withXsrfConfiguration(
    {
      cookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      headerName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    })
  ),

  authInterceptorProvider,
  importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule, KeycloakBearerInterceptor),
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
    multi: true,
    deps: [KeycloakService],
  },
  KeycloakService,
]};
```

Here my AppComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'testy';
  public isLoggedIn = false;
  public userProfile: KeycloakProfile | null = null;

  constructor(private readonly keycloak: KeycloakService,
              private http: HttpClient) { }

  public async ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoggedIn = await this.keycloak.isLoggedIn();

    if (this.isLoggedIn) {
      this.userProfile = await this.keycloak.loadUserProfile();
    }
  }

  login() {
    this.keycloak.login();
  }

  protected loadAbos() {
    this.http.get<Abo[]>('http://localhost:8080/api/abos?email=' + this.userProfile?.email, { observe: 'response',withCredentials: true })
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => this.handleError("Could not load abos", err)),
        /// if no error occurs we receive the abos
        tap(abos => {
          console.info("loaded abos", abos);
        })
      ).subscribe()
  }
```

Thanks 4 your help <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a response featuring a working example, including Angular 17 standalone and Keycloak 23
https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular/issues/384#issuecomment-1895845160

and here are full app.config.ts

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter, withComponentInputBinding, withInMemoryScrolling, withViewTransitions } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {
  provideHttpClient,
  withFetch,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {KeycloakBearerInterceptor, KeycloakService} from "keycloak-angular";
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, withInterceptorsFromDi} from "@angular/common/http";
import {APP_INITIALIZER, Provider} from '@angular/core';


export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http,'./assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      // Configuration details for Keycloak
      config: {
        url: 'http://localhost:8082', // URL of the Keycloak server
        realm: 'realm-name', // Realm to be used in Keycloak
        clientId: 'clientid' // Client ID for the application in Keycloak
      },
      // Options for Keycloak initialization
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'login-required', // Action to take on load
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
          window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html' // URI for silent SSO checks
      },
      // Enables Bearer interceptor
      enableBearerInterceptor: true,
      // Prefix for the Bearer token
      bearerPrefix: 'Bearer',
      // URLs excluded from Bearer token addition (empty by default)
      //bearerExcludedUrls: []
    });
 }
 
 // Provider for Keycloak Bearer Interceptor
 const KeycloakBearerInterceptorProvider: Provider = {
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: KeycloakBearerInterceptor,
  multi: true
 };
 
 // Provider for Keycloak Initialization
 const KeycloakInitializerProvider: Provider = {
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
  multi: true,
  deps: [KeycloakService]
 }
 
 
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()), // Provides HttpClient with interceptors
    KeycloakInitializerProvider, // Initializes Keycloak
    KeycloakBearerInterceptorProvider, // Provides Keycloak Bearer Interceptor
    KeycloakService, // Service for Keycloak 
    provideRouter(routes,withViewTransitions(),withComponentInputBinding()), 
    provideClientHydration(), 
    // provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
    provideAnimations(), 
    { provide: Document, useExisting: DOCUMENT },
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      defaultLanguage: 'ar',
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }).providers!
  ]
};
```

also I have used it in my components like

```
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-customers',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, MatIconModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatCardModule, MatToolbarModule, MatButtonModule, CustomeSearchComponent],

  templateUrl: './customers.component.html',
  styleUrl: './customers.component.scss'
})
export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor( private keycloakService: KeycloakService) {
}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const isLoggedIn = this.keycloakService.isLoggedIn();
    if (!isLoggedIn)
      this.keycloakService.login();

    const userRoles = this.keycloakService.getUserRoles();
 

    if (isLoggedIn){
       this.loadData();
    }      
  }

}

}
```

This will automatically include authentication header to your http calls